# Launching audio on TV from my android phone app using Google Chromecast

Tags: android, audio, streaming, google-cast

I want to use Google Chrome-cast API in one of my Music application.

I want to do following:

1)Connect My Android device with Google chrome-cast receiver.

2)When i click on song from application it should launch that song on receiver side(Say Audio has Straming Url).

I have read chrome-cast document from [Here](https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_overview?hl=en) and i succeed to setup and run the sample projects from [Github](https://github.com/googlecast).

Have anyone implement chromecast to launch audio file from application?

I Searched on google but didn't find much on chrome-cast to launch audio file.

Comment: I think the RAMP protocol can be used for video and audio. Try adapting the tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver. The tutorial is intended for video, but you might be able to use an audio tag: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the android sample app on github you will see that some of the media content is audio content.  Hope that helps.

https://github.com/googlecast